# 350K element array into Tree structure in PHP issue

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Hi I have following array:

```
Huge_Array (356362 elements) //used splfixedarray for better handling of this array
(
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 0
)
```

keys of this array is unique, and values showing parent of key.
like parent of 1 & 6 is 0, parent of 2 is 1, for 3 is 2....

This array is grabbing the id and parent id of a node, these node's in the table are self referencing i.e  id: 234 parentid: 345 , id:345  parentid:676. Im trying to create a tree out of these nodes, the array is created and holds the relationships of child, parent properly. However it only works for a certain limit of nodes like a couple thousand . the complete tree is suppose to be made out of an array with 350k nodes which I already have. I serialized it and get the file contents (file size 7mb), now with that array (unserlized successfully) I do the following to create the tree. This however doesn't work for a huge array though. It times out because its too large but it works for smaller arrays. What I'm I doing wrong and how can I make this support the huge array and contruct the tree in memory?

```
class node {

    var $children;


    public function __construct(){
        $this->children = array();

    }

}

$tree = array();

foreach ($Huge_array as $q => $p){

    if(!isset($tree[$p]))
        $tree[$p] = new node;
    if(!isset($tree[$q]))
        $tree[$q] = new node;

    $mark[$p]=FALSE;
    $mark[$q]=FALSE;
    array_push($tree[$p]->children,$q);

}
var_dump($tree);
```

Comment: Why should you load **whole** tree in memory? I hope you are not going to display it on web page simultaneously? You should elaborate more on your final task, so that we could give you an advice, but in general it's better to load tree branches from database on demand to avoid unnecessary overhead of loading data, that won;'t be viewed anyway (one can't browse through 350K records in one go, ain't it?).

Comment: And you can just avoid using class as node,just add subelement in $tree, the easier, the better, and cost less memory